# Test Coverage for a Email Services Class

Tags: unit-test, apex-email-service, code-coverage, code, failing-tests

Class:

```
global class EmailDemoReceive implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {


global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.Inboundenvelope envelope) {


Contact contact;
Account account;


Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

@testVisible Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
opp.Name = email.subject;
opp.Description = email.plainTextBody;
opp.StageName = 'Inquiry';
opp.CloseDate = Date.today();
insert opp;



  if ([select count() from Contact where Email = :email.fromAddress] == 0) {

      contact = new Contact();
      Account acc = [Select Id, name from Account Limit 1];
      contact.AccountId = acc.Id;
      opp.AccountID = acc.Id;

     OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
     ocr.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
     ocr.Role = 'Decision Maker';

     String fromWho = email.fromAddress;
     String s2 = fromWho.substringBefore('@');
     String first = s2.substringBefore('.');
     String last = s2.substringAfter('.');

     contact.Email = fromWho;
     contact.FirstName = first.capitalize();
     contact.LastName = last.capitalize();


      insert contact;
      ocr.ContactId = contact.Id;
      insert ocr;


    } else {
          contact = new Contact();
          contact = [select Id, AccountId, FirstName, LastName, Email from Contact where Email = :email.fromAddress Limit 1];
          opp.AccountId = contact.AccountId;
          OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
          ocr.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
          ocr.ContactId = contact.Id;
          ocr.Role = 'Decision Maker';
          insert ocr;

    }


 update opp;
 return result;  


 } 
 }
```

Here is my test class so far:

```
 isTest(SeeAllData=true)

  public class TestEmailDemoReceive{

  public static testmethod void testEmailDemoReceive(){ 
    EmailDemoReceive objconfirm = new EmailDemoReceive();

    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name = 'Coca-Cola';
    insert acc;

    // Create a new email, envelope object and Attachment

    Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();

    Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();

    email.subject = 'This is the Email Subject';

    email.plainTextBody = 'Hello, this a test email body. For testing purposes only.';

    envelope.fromAddress = 'test.testing@sometest.com';

    objconfirm.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);


    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = objconfirm.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
    System.assertEquals( result.success  ,true);

 }
 }
```

When I try and access the class in my test I get Variable does not exist: objconfim.opp.StageName and this happens when I try and access any variable. Why would this be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your EmailServices class, you have this line:

```
@testVisible Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
```

You are apparently trying to query the value of this variable in your testmethod to see if it is accurate. Instead, you need to do this:

```
Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = objconfirm.handleInboundEmail(email, envelope);
System.assertEquals( result.success  ,true);
Opportunity resOppo = [select id, stagename from Opportunity where name = :email.subject];
System.assertEquals(resOppo.stageName, 'Inquiry');
/// other asserts
```

Also, you need to get rid of `SeeAllData=true` as otherwise you might have a real Oppo with same name as your test email subject and this will cause problems when you deploy (perhaps months later)

The `@TestVisible` is mostly useful for invoking methods as part of test setup or to alter static constants more amenable to the test scenario (like a scope from default in PROD code of 200 to something like 1 or 2 in testmethod code (batch class example)

As you are using it, the value of `opp` has long gone by the time your invocation of handleInboundEmail(..) has executed